# Negating a 160bit value

Tags: assembly, x86

I was studying assembly and yesterday found a code for negating a 160bit value(to be exactly I found it here -> https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH09/CH09-5.html).

It's:

```
Value           dword   0,0,0,0,0       ;160 bit integer.
                 .
                 .
                 .
                mov     eax, 0
                sub     eax, Value
                mov     Value, eax
                mov     eax, 0
                sbb     eax, Value+4
                mov     Value+8, ax
                mov     eax, 0
                sbb     eax, Value+8
                mov     Value+8, ax
                mov     eax, 0
                sbb     eax, Value+12
                mov     Value+12, ax
                mov     eax, 0
                sbb     eax, Value+16
                mov     Value+16, ax
```

I dont know if I'm not good enough at assembly or this code contain some mistakes. Look at 6th line(counting from first **mov** operation):

```
5.   sbb     eax, Value+4
6.   mov     Value+8, ax
```

Shouldn't the 6th line look like that:

```
mov     Value+4, eax
```

I don't get it why we are **mov**ing only lower 16bits of eax to Value and why it's directly moved to Value+8 instead of Value+4.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: That's a bug. You are correct.

Comment: And in the subsequent lines: `ax` should be `eax`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 6-th line must be as you suggested and below all "ax" must be "eax":

Here is the right code in FASM syntax:

```
            mov     eax, 0
            sub     eax, [Value]
            mov     [Value], eax
            mov     eax, 0
            sbb     eax, [Value+4]
            mov     [Value+4], eax
            mov     eax, 0
            sbb     eax, [Value+8]
            mov     [Value+8], eax
            mov     eax, 0
            sbb     eax, [Value+12]
            mov     [Value+12], eax
            mov     eax, 0
            sbb     eax, [Value+16]
            mov     [Value+16], eax
```

Replacing `mov eax, 0` with `mov eax, edx` and in price of one more register used, will make the code smaller and a little bit faster on some CPUs:

```
            xor     edx, edx
            xor     eax, eax
            sub     eax, [Value]
            mov     [Value], eax
            mov     eax, edx
            sbb     eax, [Value+4]
            mov     [Value+4], eax
            mov     eax, edx
            sbb     eax, [Value+8]
            mov     [Value+8], eax
            mov     eax, edx
            sbb     eax, [Value+12]
            mov     [Value+12], eax
            mov     eax, edx
            sbb     eax, [Value+16]
            mov     [Value+16], eax
```

Comment: No, the "some_ONE" example is much fatser than yours. Remember CPU at `not` instruction read RAM, negate value and write back value to the RAM, at `adc` instruction is similar, so we read 2 times and write 2 times for one step. At "some_ONE" example we acces to RAM only two times per step, 1 read and 1 write.

Comment: Test both examples. Your example is slower for about 40%!

Comment: @GJ. Yes, you are right. Answer edited, according  to the tests. :)

Comment: Your second example is wrong because `xor` instruction modify carry flag, so you can use only `xor  eax,eax` in first line.

Comment: @GJ.: Yes, it is wrong. :( But I still don't like `mov reg32, const`. How about this version? ;)

Comment: Amm, only one more register involved. :)

Comment: @GJ. Well, registers are to be used. Personally, very often I prefer the smaller code rather than faster. :)